# How to have consistently index number in different pandas dataframe chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm using pandas to read large size file,so I use:

```
for df_small in pd.read_csv("largefile.txt", chunksize=1000,
                         iterator=True, low_memory=False):
```

and for each chunk I need add a column 'seqnum',it will the consistently index for all chunks:

```
for df_small in pd.read_csv("largefile.txt", chunksize=1000,
                             iterator=True, low_memory=False):

    df_small ['seqnum'] == df_small .index.values
```

So for the first chunk the df_small ['seqnum'] will be:

```
0
1
2
...
999
```

But the df_small ['seqnum'] of second chunk will still be:

```
0
1
2
...
999
```

That is not what I want, the ideal df_small ['seqnum']  of the second chunk should be:

```
1000
1001
1002
...
1999
```

Is there anyway can do that?

Comment: Can you update your post with few lines of your largefile.txt, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index of `df_small`:

```
for df_small in pd.read_csv("data1.csv", chunksize=3,
                             iterator=True, low_memory=False):
    df_small['seqnum'] = df_small.index.values
    print(df_small)
```

Output:

```
  Name  seqnum  # <- 1st iteration
0    A       0
1    B       1
2    C       2

  Name  seqnum  # <- 2nd iteration
3    D       3
4    E       4
5    F       5

  Name  seqnum  # <- 3rd iteration
6    G       6
7    H       7
8    I       8

   Name  seqnum  # <- 4th iteration
9     J       9
10    K      10
11    L      11
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I just updated my question please help check !

Comment: @William. I don't understand why it doesn't work for you. For me it works as expected.

Comment: It really not work for me,maybe different version ?

Comment: What is you version of Pandas?

Comment: mine is pandas (1.1.5)

Comment: I know why ,because for some reason,I used df_small..sort_index() before it,if I move your code before .sort_index,it works

Comment: Do you concat df_small at each iteration in another dataframe?

Comment: No I don't do that ,because it will be a very large size file,that we want to avoid.

Comment: Ok this is a good practice. Ty for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable to track the start index of the next chunk as follows:

```
seq_num = 0
for df_small in pd.read_csv("largefile.txt", chunksize=1000,
                         iterator=True, low_memory=False):

    df['seqnum'] = df.index + seq_num
    seq_num = df.index[-1] + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply I just updated my question please help check !

Comment: @William You need to change equality operator `==` to assignment operator `=`.